# Error on Central Admin's 'Check Database Status'

Tags: sql, sharepoint-administration

The default instance was upgraded to SQL 2019 for the server on which our SPinstance for SP2013 Enterprise resides. Our SP lives on a named instance.

ULS logs:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DatabasesDataSourceView.FillDataTable(DataTable table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DataTableDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AdministrationDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 does not support Microsoft SQL Server 2019:

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/hardware-software-requirements-2013)

Comment: True but the decision was made to do this by C-Levels despite the incompatibility.

Comment: That's a shame. By ignoring SharePoint's hardware and software requirements, they have essentially put the farm at risk (the issues are unsurprising).

Comment: I agree. And getting support from MS is a no go. And getting help from online isn't easy either.